# What is the need of plugins in Jenkins (Sonarqube)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, windows, sonarqube

On learning about integrating Sonarqube to CI/CD pipeline, I came across the Sonarqube Jenkins plugin which most of the online blogs recommends.

After configuring it, I realized that the working is the same as that of running the sonar-scanner through the command line using below command.

```
sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=test" -D"sonar.sources=." -D"sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" -D"sonar.login=erwerwerwerwer"
```

**Same is applicable for any tool, as most can be executed through command line.**

So I am confused about,

> what's the advantage of using a plugin over just running the tools as
>   windows batch command in Jenkins build step.?

Comment: More details in its documentation (and if it fails answering your question, [edit] to explain why it doesn't answer): https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any CI/CD plugin can ultimately be scripted.  However, using plugins gives you better centralized control.

**Consider the following scenario**: Your SonarQube server location has to move to a new location.

If you are using a script like the example you provided above, you would need to manually update every script.  This process is error prone as you may miss a script or worse, type the wrong address.  Instead, if you are using a plugin you can update the server location once and be done.

Comment: If I move the server , the plug-in requires same amount of rework as with plug-in. For instance, pointing to new sonarqube-scanner location and all. Ya if I choose automatic installation then your answer is correct.

Comment: @PDHide: You are correct if you have one build pipeline.  But imagine how this will scale if you had 5, 15, 100 pipelines.  One global configuration can save a lot of time in this type of setup.